# Problem in Recurring payment using money scirpts

Tags: payment-gateways

we offered 20% discount last year and I've just received a recurring payment and it should be for full amount but its the same payment as last year. It just means if people renew their membership we lose on 20% of each membership fee.

Am using MS Core 6.x-1.25 and Drupal Version 6.20

Any one can help?

Thanks

Comment: I using MS Coupons for the discount.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set it to 'Persistent' in scope, then it will remain discounted for all payments in the series. 'Initial' is what you want, where only the first payment is discounted, sort of like a Trial amount.

Comment: If we set scope as "initial" Coupon code deactivated after first payment.